# Put 2 views in a ConstraintLayout that's itself in another ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to understand how Android's `ConstraintLayout` works, and in order to do so, I want to create a layout that would take 1/4 of the view height with a left/right/bottom margin of 25dp, and in this layout, put two views, the first one would take 70% of its height and the second one the remaining 30%.

To sum up this:

[image]

I tried this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,7:10"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,3:10"
            android:background="@color/light_blue" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But instead I'm only having the bottom view (that should take 30% of the height) taking the whole layout space. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you have:**

Property `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` is "self dependable" , that is it only adjust `width`-to-`height` ratio of itself.

**What you require:**

If you're using ConstrainLayout 1.1.x you can use property `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` , which takes values from 0 to 1.

Also, you might have to adjust constrains of these views top and bottom to be relative to each other.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was using a pre 1.1.x version of `ConstraintLayout` so I didn't have access to `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` (and `width` as well).